# Number of events in boost::asio::io_service event loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

Is it possible to know the number of pending events in a boost::asio::io_service event loop? I am looking at the [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html) but not seeing any such function.

I am looking for such a functionality to implement a dynamically resizable thread pool. The number of pending events can be used, if available, to determine if I need to add more threads to the pool.

Comment: At least on Windows this is not possible with IOCP (and there should be no need, see Anton's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both the asio and your application are written correctly so the only blocking operation is inside the event dispatch loop, why would you need more threads than available HW resources? I.e. if the threads do not block than oversubscription will not bring you any performance improvement.

Thus, you can create a thread pool of fixed size or just use [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) which will create it for you to process a task (though, TBB is not yet supposed for blocking IO, so do not use TBB tasks for blocking-wait)

Comment: I understand that having more threads than available HW resources won't benefit me much, that should be how I should determine the max pool size, but what about having less thread than that when there is not many events to process and gradually add threads up to the max number if needed?

Comment: create threads on-demand. I.e. when all the threads are busy processing a task, create a new one until the limit is reached